# Can't understand why True/False isn't working

Tags: python, python-3.x

After the player takes the light bulb, "bulb" is appended to the inventory and the light_bulb variable is set to `True`. I've added `print(light_bulb)` to the code and indeed it is set to `True` once the light bulb is taken.

I can't understand why line 9 runs even when there's a `and not light_bulb:` placed at the end. The second or third or fourth time the code runs, as `light_bulb` is set to `True`; that would evaluate to `and not True` or `and False`. This means line 14 should run instead of 9, right?

```
inventory = ["null"]

def lol():
    choice1 = input(">")
    light_bulb = False
    if "bulb" in inventory:
        light_bulb = True 

    if "bulb" in choice1.lower() or "unscrew" in choice1.lower() or "lightbulb" in choice1.lower() or "light" in choice1.lower() and not light_bulb:
        inventory.append("bulb")
        print("You try to fix the light bulb but it comes off. You decide to keep it.")
        alley()

    elif "bulb" in choice1.lower() or "unscrew" in choice1.lower() or "lightbulb" in choice1.lower() and light_bulb:
        print ("You already have a light bulb!")
        alley()
    else:
        dead("You fumble around in the darkness and accidentally kill yourself.")
```

Comment: You aren't setting `light_bulb = True` in that huge-long-conditional.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm setting `light_bulb = True` here: `if "bulb" in inventory:
        light_bulb = True `. The `and not light_bulb` is just to check whether the player has the light bulb or not.

Comment: Outcome depends on you input.  What input are you typing in.  Also, for neatness, do the conversion to lower case once and the test for "lightbulb" is redundant

Comment: How do I do the conversion once?

Comment: choice1 = input(">").lower

Comment: Oh my goodness! I didn't think of that. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has to do with the order the `or` and `and` expressions are evaluated. The `and` operator has a higher precedence than the `or` expressions that precede it, so it is evaluated first. I suspect you wanted it evaluated last instead. Try adding parentheses, to make the order explicit (this also allows you to wrap the line to a more reasonable length):

```
if ("bulb" in choice1.lower() or "unscrew" in choice1.lower() or
    "lightbulb" in choice1.lower() or "light" in choice1.lower()) and not light_bulb:
```

Note that checking for the string `"lightbulb"` is probably unnecessary, since you're also checking for its substrings `"light"` and `"bulb"` separately (and the `in` operator dosn't respect word boundariers).

Answer (score 1):

The `and` operator binds more tightly than `or`. So what you wrote is equivalent to:

```
  if "bulb" in choice1.lower() or "unscrew" in choice1.lower() or "lightbulb" in choice1.lower() or ("light" in choice1.lower() and not light_bulb):
```

What you want is:

```
  if ("bulb" in choice1.lower() or "unscrew" in choice1.lower() or "lightbulb" in choice1.lower() or "light" in choice1.lower()) and not light_bulb:
```

To get that, you need the parentheses.